Password Visibility Toggle
I'm trying to use a typescript function in my page to change the icon that toggles the password visibility. this is how it's supposed to work: i press a button (in this case, a clickable icon), the icon changes and the property "type" in the input should change to "text", to allow the user to see what they have entered in this field. then, when pressed again, the icon should change to the default value and the input type should return to "password".
this is my code:
togglePasswordVisibility() {
    document.querySelector("#input2").setAttribute("type", "password")
    
    document.querySelector("#passwordIcon").setAttribute("name", "eye-off")
    
    if (document.querySelector('#passwordIcon').getAttribute('name') == 'eye-off') {
      
      document.querySelector('#passwordIcon').setAttribute("name", "eye")
    }

the problem is that it only works once, and I want it to work multiple times. Can someone help me?

This does not look like angular code. Please add more specific tags like javascript.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Your code basically states:

Set the type to password
If the type is password, set it to text

But the second part of that will always be true, that's why it only works once. So you should change it to:
togglePasswordVisibility() {    
  if (document.querySelector('#passwordIcon').getAttribute('name') == 'eye-off') {
    document.querySelector("#input2").setAttribute("type", "text")
    document.querySelector('#passwordIcon').setAttribute("name", "eye-off");
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#input2").setAttribute("type", "password");
    document.querySelector("#passwordIcon").setAttribute("name", "eye");
  }
}


tried your code and it worked, but in the opposite way, so i changed the first statement to  if (document.querySelector("#passwordIcon").getAttribute("name") == "eye")  and the third statement to document.querySelector("#passwordIcon").setAttribute("name", "eye-off")"  and it works just fine!!!
thank you for helping me!

Instead of implementing this functionality using JS, if you are using the latest ionic v8, then by default it provides a component ion-input-password-toggle to provide the behaviour of changing the visibility of text inside input on button click.
<ion-input type="password" label="Password" value="YourPassword">
  <ion-input-password-toggle slot="end"></ion-input-password-toggle>
</ion-input>


i tried it, but it doesn't work properly and the documentation is too vague about this component :(

Can you share your code with these changes, because I would like to know the issue you are having?

already solved it with other solution :p
still, i think the documentation isn't as objective as it should be. The only thing they say is to put the tag  and nothing else
